# How to get logger.info of Flask app in Waitress in windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, logging, waitress

I have the flask app serving in waitress in windows, I have logger info

```
app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

@app.route('/run', methods=['POST'])
def RunFunction():
    …………codes...……..
    app.logger.info("Log 1: Starting App on Port: {}".format(LISTEN_PORT))
    …………...
```

If I run with flask, I get the logger info

```
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app.run(debug=True,port=8080, threaded=True,use_reloader=False)
```

If I use in waitress

```
from waitress import serve
serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', threads=WAITRESS_THREADS, port=LISTEN_PORT)
```

I am not getting logger info in console

I tried

```
app = Flask(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger('waitress')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

and logger codes as

```
logger.info("Log 1: Starting App on Port: {}".format(LISTEN_PORT))
```

This is not working

Also I tried

```
from paste.translogger import TransLogger 
serve(TransLogger(app, setup_console_handler=True), host='0.0.0.0', threads=WAITRESS_THREADS, port=LISTEN_PORT)
```

This also not working, may I know how to get the logger info in waitress

Comment: How about:

```python
app = Flask(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger('waitress')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

followed by:

```python
logger.info("Log 1: Starting App on Port: {}".format(LISTEN_PORT))
```

Comment: If you set the level to `ERROR`, `INFO` log lines will not show up.